# How to present a pdf object using Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, pdf

How can I render a pdf stream in a new memory using win32 API ?

I know that ShellExecute can be used if the file is already saved on disk but what if I want to do that without having to first save the file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, win32 doesn't include a way to natively display PDF files. So I think your only choice is to save it to disk (perhaps in a temporary folder somewhere) and then use ShellExecute or equivalent to launch it, and hope the user has a PDF viewing application installed. :(

Edit: Andreas in a comment to this answer mentioned that there's an ActiveX control you should use, if you can rely on Adobe Acrobat being installed.

Comment: Or you could use the ActiveX control, as web browsers and e-mail clients do. But still, you need Adobe Reader installed.

Comment: You can read my answer if you're interested embedding PDF file into native Windows program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**MuPDF**](http://mupdf.com/) to render PDF in native Win32 program.

Learn the **SumatraPDF** source code to see how it works (**SumatraPDF** itself use **MuPDF**).